# Problems making migrations with mysqlclient whit Django virtual enviroment

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, virtualenv

I want to make a mysql database connection using django, and I have downloaded the mysqlclient packages to do this, but when I use `python manage.py makemigrations` it throws me the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 36, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

I had alredy install mysql client newer version, if I try to run `pip install --upgrade mysqlclient` it says:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: mysqlclient in /Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.2.post1)
```

I'm using a Anaconda virtual enviroment and I have python 3.7.3 installed. Also I'm working on OSX. How can I solve this?

Comment: Run `python -c "import MySQLdb; print(MySQLdb.__file__)"` and check where the file comes from; if it's from `/Users/paulmirve/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, then your virtual env looks broken. If not, something else modifies `sys.path` - run `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.sep.join(sys.path))"` and check what comes before the env import paths.

Comment: It comes from `python -c "import MySQLdb; print(MySQLdb.__file__)"` so I suppose  the env is broken. Do you know how can I fix it?